# How do i continuously update a value if it changed on the database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, wpf

I'm trying to implement the status of a current logged in user in an WPF application. I can read from the database and set that value once , but i need it to keep updating. So for example when a user is online, and  he changes to busy. The value would be online, but once it changed on the database to busy , the value would update to busy too.

for example:

```
  connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
  Query = "SELECT status FROM Accounts WHERE username=@username";
  connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

  MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(Query, connection);
  command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", thedesiredusername);
  connection.Open();
  MySqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

  while (dataReader.Read())
  {
     string userstatus = dataReader.GetString("status");
  }
```

This would set the userstatus value once. How can i get it to do something like this:

```
connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
Query = "SELECT status FROM Accounts WHERE username=@username";
connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(Query, connection);
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", thedesiredusername);
connection.Open();
MySqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (dataReader.Read())
{
   //keep doing:
   if (userstatus != dataReader.GetString("status"))
   {
     string userstatus = dataReader.GetString("status");
   }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: look up SQL dependencies

Comment: you could also have a server that manages all the state.

Comment: I'm looking it up .

Comment: @DanielA.White So i've tried the sqldependency thing and i can't connect it to my mysql database. for some reason it sais the connection string is not valid even though i have verified in multiple ways that it is.

Comment: theres a mssql dependency and a mysql dependency - make sure you use the right one.

Comment: @DanielA.White Thank you. I found a MySql package named Devart.Data.MySql and installed it . I played around a bit with that and this should do the trick. But once i open its connection it gives me the following error: _Devart.Common.LicenseException: 'Feature is not supported.'_ I will update the question with the code.

Comment: that is a separate question from your main question.

Comment: Allright i'll make a new question for that then. i'll just mark this as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now using Devart.Data.MySql Package. this does exactly what i need.

Answer (score 1):

If you can identify when the login state will change or can identify an event that's convenient to check (page load), event driven models are typically more efficient.  If you don't have this luxury, then you're left polling the database every so often to see if the status has changed.  Consider adding the filter to the database query rather than the client side code.

Typically, the database query is the most expensive part of the polling check.  Trying to save a couple of processing cycles by checking if the new acquired matches the last check, isn't providing any sort of massive performance boost.

Comment: Allright thanks. i'll see if i can do the first thing tommorow.

Comment: the polling thing would work but is kind of a pain in the ass to have as it makes the program not smooth at all . I forgot to mention it's a WPF program . What do you mean '
1
down vote
accept
If you can identify when the login state will change or can identify an event that's convenient to check (page load),' i don't know how i would do this ?